# [ Directory '../../etc/postgresql/9.3/main' does not exist ]

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to change **pg_hba.conf** but when I inter `sudo nano ../../etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf` i got on the screen [ Directory '../../etc/postgresql/9.3/main' does not exist ] i have fallow all the things[Install PostgreSQL](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-postgres) I am working compute engine

Answer (score 0):

Try to locate pg_hba.conf with following coomand.

```
find / | grep pg_hba.conf
```

May be you installed a different version of postgresql.

Comment: I found the same version `/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf  
/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/.pg_hba.conf.swp`

Comment: yes it helps me tell me more

Answer (score 0):

You are using a relative path and probably you are not in the directory mentioned in the manual.

`../` is the path to the parent directory. In in case you are currently in the user's home directory `../../` is the path to the root directory `/`.

The solution is to use absolute path, so tray with:

```
sudo nano /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf
```

Comment: it does not work I have try this

Answer (score 0):

Once you located pg_hba.conf you can edit the file.

In your case it should be

```
sudo nano /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf
```

You also can move to

```
cd /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/
```

and edit the the file from there

```
sudo nano pg_hba.conf
```